# Can somebody explain why window.location.href twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I click a button with `JQuery` it will send a `Ajax` post and then return a location in returned data. However when the location has been refreshed already with the `window.location.href` once  and I go to click the button again  the `window.location.href` will not work but the data is returned correctly.

Any ideas?

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_pupil_quad_blog_member", function(){
        var member_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("remove_member_", "");
        var group_id = $("input[name='pupil_quad_group_id']").val();
        $.post("/ajax/admin/school.design.ajax.php", {cmd:'remove_pupil_quad_blog_member', group_id: group_id, member_id: member_id, dataType: 'json'}, function(data){
            var JSON_Message = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(JSON_Message.new_location);
            window.location.href = JSON_Message.new_location;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @JesperHøjer - No errors given, it's returning everything it should. It's just not relocating with the window.location.href on second button click.

Comment: Second button click would be first button click - correct? Because you click on button, page loads and then you click again the button. Only difference is, that `window.location.href` is equal to the value in `JSON_Message.new_location`.

Comment: @Jurik Correct. So you can't relocate if it's equal to current `window.location.href` ?

Comment: I tested it with my browser console and it worked. So I have no clue why it is not reloading in your case.

Comment: I tested it with Chrome - what browser do you use?

Comment: @Jurik it's worked. I've changed it to if it's already equalling the `window.location.href` then just refresh page.